# Type of statement given a function with polymorphic type ocaml

Tags: ocaml, computer-science

If I have a function with polymorphic type

```
f : 'a -> 'a * 'a -> ('a * 'a) list
```

I also have:

```
type test = float * float
```

What will be the type of the following statement?

```
let ab: test = (0., 0.) in fun x -> f x test
```

I'm confused with the `x` here, is it the name of `fun` or it's simply input of `fun`, cause the input for `f` should be `'a`, but not `'a -> 'a`.
Right now I'm thinking if the type of the statement should be:

```
'a -> test * test -> (test * test) list
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a good tool to try all your hypothesis on OCaml type system at hand: the OCaml REPL.

Currently,

```
type test = float * float
exception Hole
let f: 'a -> ('a * 'a) -> ('a * 'a) list = fun x -> fun y -> raise Hole
let mysterious  =
  let ab: test = (0., 0.) in fun x -> f x cd
```

yields

```
  Error: Unbound value cd
```

Thus the `mysterious` expression doesn't have a type because it is not well defined.

EDIT: After correcting the typo,

```ml
let mysterious  =
  let ab: test = (0., 0.) in fun x -> f x ab
```

will yield the correct type. Then you should compare this type with the one you obtained by applying the type inference rule by hand to catch your mistake.

However, without knowing how you concluded that the type of `mysterious` was `'a -> test * test -> (test * test) list` it is hard to pinpoint the first mistake in your reasoning.

Comment: sorry, my bad, there's a typo in the statement, it should be `let ab: test = (0., 0.) in fun x -> f x test`, I've edited it

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some basic syntax confusion regarding functions.

```
fun x -> ...
```

You've introduced an *anonymous* function that takes an argument named `x` and returns some other value.

If you wish to give that function a name, you can bind a name to it.

```
let foo = fun x -> ...
```

Note that the following is equivalent.

```
let foo x = ...
```